# Docker, Docker compose - how to run RSpec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rspec-rails

Can anybody point it out, - what is the best approach to run RSpec tests on a Rails  API app inside a Docker container (during the container build/run) ?

The aim is to be able to separate the development environment from other ones and to run tests only in `development` mode, start Puma server only in `staging, production` environments.

What is the right place to put `bundle exec rspec` command, - in a separate `entrypoint.sh` script, Directly in `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose.yml` file, or other solutions?

All the Googles results as well as [Docker for Rails Developers](https://pragprog.com/book/ridocker/docker-for-rails-developers) book by PragProg have no examples and the only way to run the tests theys provide is to run them against an already running container.

Actually, my `Dockerfile` looks like that:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.1

RUN apt-get update -yqq
RUN apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends build-essential zip unzip libpq-dev libaio1 libaio-dev nodejs

ENV APP_HOME=/usr/src/app
ENV BUNDLE_PATH /gems

COPY . $APP_HOME

RUN echo "gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri" >> ~/.gemrc

WORKDIR $APP_HOME
RUN gem update --system
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

The `entrypoint.sh` looks like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if [ -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

./wait-for-it.sh ${DATABASE_HOST}:${DATABASE_PORT}

if [ -z "$RAILS_ENV" ]; then
  echo "RAILS_ENV variable is not set, will use development by default"
  bundle exec rails db:reset
  bundle exec rails db:migrate
  bundle exec rspec
else
  bundle exec rails s -e $RAILS_ENV -p 3000 -b 0.0.0.0
fi
```

And finally, `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  api:
    build: ../..
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - gem_cache:/gems
    env_file:
      - ./env/database.env
      - ./env/web.env
    depends_on:
      - database
    # Keeps the stdin open, so we can attach to our app container's process and
    # do stuff such as `byebug` or `binding.pry`:
    stdin_open: true
    # Allows us to send signals (CTRL+C, CTRL+P + CTRL+Q) into the container
    tty: true
  database:
    image: postgres:9.6
    env_file:
      - ./env/database.env
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
volumes:
  db-data:
  gem_cache:
```

Comment: Is this not actually working, or this is a question of whether or not how you have it written is acceptable?

Comment: @streetlogics, it is not actually working, DB host is not accessible. It is just an extract of the settings. Because the image is built and pushed to Rancher. So it is both: either it is an acceptable way to do that or not as well. Maybe to run tests, we do not have to use Docker but other pipelines or smth like that depending on available tools (GitLab, GitHub, etc.). I'll create a separate classic Docker app and see if it works.

Comment: As far as I could get from multiple posts, I came to the conclusion that running tests in a Docker container is not really a good step, - sometimes it can take much time and your image will take much time as well to be built. The main purpose of building an image is to provide a production-like environment without the need to install anything to your machine. It would be better to use a different pipeline to run tests in the development branch, then build a production/staging ready image without dev/test dependencies.

Comment: I've done this pipeline before - it took separate docker-compose files so that the "test" environment gets it's own DB built and seeded during the run instead of relying on a pre-existing db.  It's entirely possible.  There are certainly the limitations you mention, but at the same time, especially if I'm running integration tests, i would prefer the tests to be run again an application environment that better mimics my production environment vs. my development environment, especially if I'm using Docker in production.

Answer (score 9):

try

```
docker-compose run -e "RAILS_ENV=test" api bundle exec rspec spec/link/to/file.rb
```

Answer (score 2):

You should run `bundle exec rspec` on your host, *before* you run any Docker commands.

```sh
# Install and test the application locally
bundle install
bundle exec rspec
bundle exec rails server

# Great, it works; now package and run it in Docker
docker build -t ... .
docker run -p ... --net ... --name ... ...
```

You might find it useful to set up a partial Docker Compose environment with some dependencies.  You can start these up before you run your test.

```sh
docker-compose up -d mysql redis
# Change config/settings.yml and config/database.yml to point at localhost
bundle exec rails rspec
```

You'll hit two practical problems trying to run tests in Docker.

1. If you try to run tests in the Dockerfile, that doesn't have access to any of the other services that might be defined in the same `docker-compose.yml` file.  In the particular case of Active Record, the application is actually unable to start, and you can't even run unit-type tests, without the database available.  So you can't really run tests in the Dockerfile.
2. If you try to run tests at application startup, you need to include all of your test dependencies in the Docker image (which increases your image size and potential security attack surface).  You need to decide whether you always want to run tests (which increases startup time, possibly significantly) or only run them sometimes (which is awkward in a plain Docker Compose setup, though pretty straightforward in more robust CI systems).

Comment: I updated the comment, you can see that I'm using `wait-for-it` script to check if the database is available.

Comment: thank you for your response, it confirmed my ideas about the need  to integrate dev, test environment in a Docker image, - it is sooooo long.

Answer (score 2):

I found this worked for me:

```
# docker-compose.yml

# Shared config from my compose file
x-app_config: &app_config
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
  stdin_open: true
  tty: true
  environment: &env
    RAILS_ENV: ${RAILS_ENV:-development}
  volumes:
    - .:/app

 # ...

 test:
   <<: *app_config
   environment:
     <<: *env
     RAILS_ENV: test
   entrypoint: ["bundle", "exec", "rspec"]
```

Now run the test:

```
docker-compose run test ./specs/path/to/your/test_spec.rb
```

Hope that helps someone :)